# SUM for different ranges

Tags: excel, vba, sum, range

I have a file where I create a Pivot Table, I copy & paste, and then format it.

The issue: Instead of Value I need the totals to be a formula (users will update figures and add lines to it).

I did it manually in the past (added a sum on each total).

Is there another option? I was thinking on the lines of "add sum formula if cell contains Number and it is Blue; sum all not coloured cells above it".

[image]

Comment: "add sum formula if cell contains Number..."  So you're saying you want to replace the number with a formula?

Comment: Where I have totals (highlighted in blue), I need it to sum the numbers just above.

Comment: With the data, could you just use a Pivot Table?  I'd venture to say that a formula to do what you want might work, but you'd be better off trying to put the raw data together so you can use a Pivot Table which is much more dynamic.

Comment: I create a pivot table and then the Excel output.  Why? Because people will add comments to it, add lines, update figures etc; so I need something "flexible". I could add SUM manually, but it is time-consuming and I am quite sure that people will add lines and not adjust the formula, so I would have to do this check myself.

Comment: If you use VBA to loop through the rows to evaluate the string in Column D, you could add the SUM formula each time you hit a line that contains "Total".  The SUM formula will update to include any lines added above it - if they are within the formula's range, right?

Comment: @Sean, This is what I am thinking on doing. The issue is that I don't know how (or even if it is possible) to say 'add sum when line has total, stop SUM -1 line before next total)

Comment: Answering my own question: you can go to "Data" and then select "Subtotal". The thing to keep in mind is that you need to remove all existing subtotals and then run the "Subtotal" option on Excel, as this action will create all the subtotals for you.